# Bootstrap: rows overlaping & height inconsistency

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to make a simple web application using bootstrap.
However I'm facing some problems related to the way I want things to be shown: Rows are overlapping one over the one before it, and I also noticed that the height of my rows are set to 0 even though the content of those rows have the correct height and are shown just how I want them.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">Some title</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="MiddlePreviewBox">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="MiddlePreviewBox">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="MiddlePreviewBox">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="MiddlePreviewBox">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS (less)

```
@border-width: 1px;
@aquaClear: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.4);
@aqua: rgba(0, 255, 255, 1);
@whiteClear: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
@whiteTransparent: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
@orange: rgb(255,165,0);

body {
    background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50) !important;
}

.container {
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.619);
}


// Using variables
.MiddlePreviewBox {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 50%; //Ratio 1:0.5
    background-color: green;
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position-x: -200px;
    background-image: url(http://www.imagendigital.com/web/img/global/leon_imagen_digital.jpg);


}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; /* <-- just a default, can be anything. */
}
```

Here's the code (Codepen.io):

https://codepen.io/julianbautista87/pen/WjJWGg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have positioned the `MiddlePreviewBox` to `absolute`, there is no need to do this. Just remove `absolute` and set `margin-top:20px;` to `.wrapper` class.

**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWBGde)**

Answer (score 0):

your container is overlaping with row
i suggest the following code change:

```css
.container {
   /* background-color: white; remove*/
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.619);
}
#title-row{
  background-color: white;
}
```

also add id #title-row in the row with words some title.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this doesn't solve my problems (a color change will only hide the overlapping problem, since there should be 4 boxes being shown, and the height of the container doesn't match it's content's height).